# Confusion about Object.create() vs Object Literals

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am currently completing the front-end web development course offered by [Meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook).

I am confused with the usage of Object.create() and Object Literals. Let's use the following code for the reference:

```
let bird = {
  hasWings: true,
  canFly: true,
  hasFeathers: true
};

let eagle = bird;
console.log("Eagle can fly: ", eagle.canFly); //"Eagle can fly: " true
eagle.canFly = false;
console.log("Eagle can fly: ", eagle.canFly); // "Eagle can fly: " false

let penguin = Object.create(bird);
penguin.canFly = false;
console.log("Penguin can fly: ", penguin.canFly); //"Penguin can fly: " false
```

If I can achieve the same results by simply using the `object literals like in case of eagle, then what difference does using` Object.create()` make in the case of penguin?

I tried to take help from ChatGPT, but it was confusing.

Comment: `let eagle = bird;` doesn't make a new bird object, `eagle` is a reference to the same object as `bird`. Add `console.log(bird.canFly);` after you do the assignment and you'll see the problem.

Comment: "If I can achieve the same results" — As Barmer points out, if you `console.log(eagle, penguin)` at the *end* of your code, you'll see that you *don't* achieve the same results. (Voting to close as cannot reproduce).

Comment: from the documentation: The `Object.create()` static method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object.

Comment: *object references* - it's not obvious when you start, eg `let a = 1; let b = 2; a=3; console.log(a,b);` gives you `3 2`.  *But* `let a = { value: 1 }; let b = a; a.value = 3; console.log(a.value, b.value)` gives you `3 3` because, when using an object, `b = a` makes b "point to a" - ie be the same reference, so changes to b also change a.

Comment: @freedomn-m It *doesn't* point to the variable `a`. Rather, both `a` and `b` hold a reference to the same *object*, whose properties you can access (and change) through both `a` and `b`. But assigning one variable never affects the other variable.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the subtle clarification.   `b=a` makes `b` point to the same object as `a` is currently pointing to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code, I could rewrite something like this:

```
let bird = {
  hasWings: true,
  canFly: true,
  hasFeathers: true
};

let eagle = bird;
console.log("Eagle can fly: ", eagle.canFly); //"Eagle can fly: " true
eagle.canFly = false;
console.log("Eagle can fly: ", eagle.canFly); // "Eagle can fly: " false

// but you changed BIRD also!!!
console.log("Bird can fly: ", bird.canFly); // Bird cannot fly :(
bird.canFly = true;
console.log("Bird can fly: ", bird.canFly); // Bird can fly again :)
// but you changed EAGLE again!
console.log("Eagle can fly: ", eagle.canFly); // Eagle can fly again, even if you set false before
```

To avoid those problems, `Object.create()` will give you a new object without any references from other objects.

`let eagle = Object.create(bird);`

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a lot of details that we need to explain here, so let us start one by one.

The **Object.create** by definition creates an another object and sets its prototype to the object that you have passed as the first argument.

Essentially in your case when you created the ***penguin*** object, you retrieved an empty object and set its prototype to the ***bird*** object.
Try logging the ***penguin*** object and take a look at its properties, you will be much surprised.

This is a mechanism that Javascript uses in order to manage inheritance called **prototype chaining**.

As you can see the **Object.create** method is not as straight forward as it seems and I would encourage you to read more about it on the following links.

[Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

[Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

The difference between using *Object Literals* and the **Object.create** method is that they are used to achieve different results in a very fundamental level.

Additionally, keep in mind that when you are assigning the **bird** object directly to the **eagle**, you are not storing its value, but its actual reference.

Both the **bird**, and the **eagle** variables are pointing out to the same object in memory and that is why changing a property in one of the objects will be reflected in the other one. Now essentially if you want to store a fresh copy of the **bird** object in the eagle variable I would suggest using the following method:

```js
let bird = {
  hasWings: true,
  canFly: true,
  hasFeathers: true
};

let eagle = {...bird};
```

Doing this, will let you have two independent objects and modifying the values in one object will not affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is a lot missing here.

1. To fully appreciate Object.create, you must understand prototypal inheritance
2. When you do something like `let eagle = bird`, you are not creating a new object, eagle. You are just creating a new reference, eagle, that is pointing to the bird object

From your code, I see that you are trying to do the following:

1. Create a generic bird
2. Create an eagle, which is a type of bird
3. Create a penguin, which is a type of bird

You want eagles and penguins to 'inherit' the properties of birds.

1. Create a generic bird using an object literal

   ```
   let bird = {
       hasWings: true,
       canFly: true,
       hasFeathers: true
   };
   ```
2. Create an eagle

   ```
   let eagle = Object.create(bird)
   ```

By using object.create, you are setting the prototype of eagle to be bird.
Try this in the console:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(eagle) === bird
```

It will evaluate to true.

Now, when you call eagle.canFly, the JavaScript runtime will check if the eagle object has a canFly property. It does not. So it'll move up the prototype chain and check bird. bird does have the canFly property, and its set to true. Hence eagle.canFly will evaluate to true.

Honestly, there's a lot to fix here. I actually wrote a series on prototypal inheritance. I recommend going though it:

[Part 1 - Understanding the Prototype Chain](https://medium.com/@aseelaldallal/javascript-the-prototype-chain-dfde1d3b22a2)

[Part 2 - Prototypal Inheritance with Object.create](https://medium.com/@aseelaldallal/javascript-the-prototype-chain-e9b2bf493ab4)

[Part 3 - Prototypal Inheritance with Constructor Functions](https://medium.com/@aseelaldallal/prototypal-inheritance-with-constructor-functions-8b9dbaaeb7f7)